# how to filter data from json by language?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

how to filter data from json by language in order to get information from the data array only the one in which the name of the city is written in English?

`[{"id": 1, "name": "Brest"},{"id": 2, "name": "Гомель"},{"id": 3, "name": "Minsk"},{"id": 4, "name": "Могилев"},{"id": 5, "name": "Лида"},{"id": 6, "name": "Бобруйск"},{"id": 7, "name": "Lida"},{"id": 8, "name": "Борисов"}]`

Comment: What have you tried? What have you found in your research about identifying languages?

Comment: i just want words from languages ​​other than english to be removed from the array

Comment: `...the one in which the name of the city is written in English..`, really?, or do you mean Latin alphabet?
I'm asking because `Minsk` may be in English, but it is also in French and probably other Latin based languages.

Comment: Incoherent. What does "written in English" even mean, for a place name?

Answer (score 0):

```
func isInAlphabet(name: String) -> Bool {
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnoiprstuvyz")

    if let _ = name.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet, options: .caseInsensitive) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

print(isInAlphabet(name: "john"))
print(isInAlphabet(name: "Лида"))
```

result

```
true
false
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

decode your data to your model and filter out based on alphabet.